# "OSERROR -10000 Apple event handler failed" when trying to change desktop wallpaper on Mac

Tags: python, macos, debugging, py-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

I have written the following really simple python script to change the desktop wallpaper on my mac (based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x)):

```
from appscript import app, mactypes
import sys 

fileName = sys.argv[1:]

app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(fileName))
```

However when I run it I get the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "../Source/SetWallPaper2.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(fileName))
>   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/appscript-0.19.0-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/appscript/reference.py", line 513, in **call**
>   appscript.reference.CommandError:
>   Command failed:       OSERROR: -10000
>         MESSAGE: Apple event handler failed.
>         COMMAND:
>   app(u'/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(u"/Users/Daniel/Pictures/['test.jpg']"))

I've done some web searching but I can't find anything to help me figure out what OSERROR -10000 means or how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileName = sys.argv[1]`
instead of
`fileName = sys.argv[1:]`

`mactypes.File(u"/Users/Daniel/Pictures/['test.jpg']")`

See the square brackets and quotes around the filename?