# How to Change Windows background using Python 2.7.3

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ctypes

I am using windows 8 (not yet updated to 8.1)

The code I am using is

> import ctypes
>
> SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
>
> ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "word.jpg", 0)
>
> print "hi"

For some reason regardless if i give it a valid image (in the same directory as program) or not, regardless of type of image (bmp, gif, jpg) the code always ends up setting my background to a black screen.

Why is this? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Some of the common problems you're hitting  (absolute path, SPIF_*) are covered with an example solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943733/change-windows-background-from-python/30697233#30697233

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `SPIF_SENDCHANGE` (which is *2*) as the last parameter. You might also need to bitwise-or it with `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` (which is *1*).

Comment: It doesn't normalize the path when persisting to the user profile with `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE`. However, loading the image uses [`SearchPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527), which searches the system `%PATH%` and the current directory. So if you use an absolute path or store the file in a `%PATH%` directory, you shouldn't get a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is late, but the problem is that you need to include the path. Instead of "image.jpg" do r"C:\path to file\image.jpg" Otherwise python doesn't know where to look for the image.