# Is it possible to use IDesktopWallpaper in Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I have a simple code for changing wallpaper:

```
import ctypes
import random
import os

start_path = "D:/my_wallpapers"
list_images = os.listdir(start_path)
img_path = os.path.join(start_path, random.choice(list_images))

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, img_path, 0)
```

I have two monitors. This code sets the same image to both monitors. I want to set different images.I discovered that there is IDesktopWallpaper (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-setwallpaper). Is it possible to use IDesktopWallpaper in Python?

I ask for help, write code so that the IdesktopWallpaper can be launched through Python 3.
With respect, Maxim.

p.s. I use windows 10 64-bit

p.s.2.
Especially for **Strive Sun - MSFT**
It seems to me that I was able to solve the first question. I was able to transfer id_monitour to DLL.

```
    void SetWallpaper(int id_mon)
{
    std::wstring s = L"D:\\images\\my_img.jpg";
    HRESULT  ad;
    UINT count;
    WCHAR* mid = new WCHAR[200];
    WCHAR* temp = mid;
    memset(mid, 0, 200 * 2);
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IDesktopWallpaper* p;
    if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DesktopWallpaper), 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(IDesktopWallpaper), (void**)&p))) {
        p->GetMonitorDevicePathCount(&count); //count: the numbers of monitor
        if (id_mon!=0) {
            p->GetMonitorDevicePathAt(id_mon-1, &mid);  //1: first monitor  2: second monitor, etc...
            ad = p->SetWallpaper(mid, s.c_str());
        }
        else {
            ad = p->SetWallpaper(NULL, s.c_str()); // 0: both monitors
        }
        p->Release();
    }
    delete[] temp;
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

But transfer the path_to_my_img.jpg, I could not. I do not understand what is going on in C ++ with the String parameter. I tried to take advantage of char, but I could not convert char in wstring

Comment: Any COM interface can be made available to Python, although the Windows API bindings support in Python looks to be quite the mess. It's mostly hit and miss, and in this case it's a miss. You're going to have to write your own bindings. The PythonCOM module provides the building blocks.

Comment: Thanks, but alas without a ready-made example or DLL, I will not cope.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to call the C++ DLL from python, there is no need to deal with some syntax problems of the com interface in python.

.py

```
import os
import sys
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('D:\\Sample\\Debug\\Sample.dll')
lib.SetWallpaper(0,'C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\panda.png')
```

.dll

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "Shobjidl.h"

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport)
        void SetWallpaper(int id, const wchar_t* s)
    {          
        HRESULT  ad;
        UINT count;
        WCHAR* mid = new WCHAR[200];
        WCHAR* temp = mid;
        memset(mid, 0, 200 * 2);
        CoInitialize(NULL);

        IDesktopWallpaper* p;
        if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DesktopWallpaper), 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(IDesktopWallpaper), (void**)&p))) {
            p->GetMonitorDevicePathCount(&count); //count: the numbers of monitor
            p->GetMonitorDevicePathAt(id, &mid);  //0: the first monitor  1: the second monitor
            ad = p->SetWallpaper(mid, s);
            p->Release();
        }
        delete[] temp;
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

If you don’t know how to create a simple dll, please refer: [Walkthrough: Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Updated:

You need to install a vs compiler, such as VS2019, and then follow the steps below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand why to do a new DLL? After all, it should already be in Windows, starting with version 8. I just need to connect to the DLL, in which IdesktopWallpaper is already lying. Sorry for my English. p.s. I do not have enough experience to make at least something on C ++.

Comment: @MaxBolovsky You can implement your needs in dll, without worrying about the syntax of winapi in python. Of course, you can also call the com interface in python, see some examples: [How to use IFileOperation from ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes)

Comment: @MaxBolovsky Some obscure winapi examples in python are rarely found, which is why I cannot provide a sample of using IDesktopWallpaper in python. ps: Python is not my specialty.

Comment: Thank you, you did everything you could.

Comment: @MaxBolovsky As I described, creating your own dll is an efficient solution. And the method of creating dll is not cumbersome, if you need, I can provide you with some tutorial help.

Comment: Hi friend. I'm trying to make DLL. But in the example (if you go to the Microsoft site) there is a *.h file. I do not understand which contents put in my file *.h.
I set Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. Selected "Create DLL". Called "idw". Made idw.h. But I do not know which code it is necessary to put in my "idw.h" file. Can you help me?

Comment: I apologize, I (possibly) does not correctly understand the C ++ code. It seems to me that in the code it is not possible to transfer the path parameter to the image.
I see a string 

std::wstring s = L"C:\\Users\\xyz\\panda.png";

But I want to send (in the setwallpaper function), the path to my picture.
I also see 

ad = p->SetWallpaper(NULL, s.c_str());

The NULL parameter sets the same picture on both monitors.
But I need to transfer the Monitorid parameter so that I can put my picture only on the monitor that I need.

Comment: @MaxBelovsky I have updated the answer and attached some images to describe the details. I have also modified the code for setting up a single monitor. Note: After copying and pasting the C++ code, you need to use `build` to compile the code, and finally get the dll file. Then put the dll file path into the python code.

Comment: Thanks friend, it is a huge job. Thanks to you, I was able to make DLL. But it does not work as I need.
I need to specify lib.setwallpaper (id_monitor, path_to_my.jpg) in Python

Comment: As far as I see, this DLL does not accept parameters.
I tried different meanings:
lib.SetWallpaper()
lib.SetWallpaper(0)
lib.SetWallpaper(1)
lib.SetWallpaper(0, path_to_my.jpg)
lib.SetWallpaper(1, path_to_my.jpg)
lib.SetWallpaper(path_to_my.jpg)
lib.SetWallpaper("1", path_to_my.jpg)
But everywhere was the same result.
Installed the picture, which is indicated in the DLL, and I wanted to transmit the parameters:
lib.SetWallpaper (id_monitor, path_to_my.jpg)
id_mon: 0 - both, 1 - first monitor, 2 - second monitor, etc...

Comment: @MaxBelovsky The dll can accept parameters. I have modified the dll and python code, please try them.

Comment: Thank you, thanks again and thanks again. You helped me to make the most important part. All functionality. Now I will do my program further. I no longer hoped. But you turned out to be the best person in the world. You did exactly what I wanted. In Russian, the word thanks, it sounds like this: "SPASI-BO". In this pronunciation there are two words that can be translated into English as:
"Let God, will save you."

Comment: @MaxBelovsky I'm glad to help you, if you have any other questions, please feel free to let me know. You can also [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) at any time.

Answer (score 1):

No need to compile a new DLL, you can use COM interface as a wrapper. This is what I'm using:

```py
import random
from ctypes import HRESULT, POINTER, pointer
from ctypes.wintypes import LPCWSTR, UINT, LPWSTR

import comtypes
from comtypes import IUnknown, GUID, COMMETHOD


# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class IDesktopWallpaper(IUnknown):
    # Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper

    # Search `IDesktopWallpaper` in `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface` to obtain the magic string
    _iid_ = GUID('{B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B}')

    @classmethod
    def CoCreateInstance(cls):
        # Search `Desktop Wallpaper` in `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` to obtain the magic string
        class_id = GUID('{C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD}')
        return comtypes.CoCreateInstance(class_id, interface=cls)

    _methods_ = [
        COMMETHOD(
            [], HRESULT, 'SetWallpaper',
            (['in'], LPCWSTR, 'monitorID'),
            (['in'], LPCWSTR, 'wallpaper'),
        ),
        COMMETHOD(
            [], HRESULT, 'GetWallpaper',
            (['in'], LPCWSTR, 'monitorID'),
            (['out'], POINTER(LPWSTR), 'wallpaper'),
        ),
        COMMETHOD(
            [], HRESULT, 'GetMonitorDevicePathAt',
            (['in'], UINT, 'monitorIndex'),
            (['out'], POINTER(LPWSTR), 'monitorID'),
        ),
        COMMETHOD(
            [], HRESULT, 'GetMonitorDevicePathCount',
            (['out'], POINTER(UINT), 'count'),
        ),
    ]

    def SetWallpaper(self, monitorId: str, wallpaper: str):
        self.__com_SetWallpaper(LPCWSTR(monitorId), LPCWSTR(wallpaper))

    def GetWallpaper(self, monitorId: str) -> str:
        wallpaper = LPWSTR()
        self.__com_GetWallpaper(LPCWSTR(monitorId), pointer(wallpaper))
        return wallpaper.value

    def GetMonitorDevicePathAt(self, monitorIndex: int) -> str:
        monitorId = LPWSTR()
        self.__com_GetMonitorDevicePathAt(UINT(monitorIndex), pointer(monitorId))
        return monitorId.value

    def GetMonitorDevicePathCount(self) -> int:
        count = UINT()
        self.__com_GetMonitorDevicePathCount(pointer(count))
        return count.value


def main():
    wallpapers = [*map(str, IMG_LIBRARY_DIR.iterdir())]

    desktop_wallpaper = IDesktopWallpaper.CoCreateInstance()
    monitor_count = desktop_wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathCount()
    for i in range(monitor_count):
        monitor_id = desktop_wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathAt(i)
        wallpaper = random.choice(wallpapers)
        desktop_wallpaper.SetWallpaper(monitor_id, str(wallpaper))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Dependency: `comtypes`