Change wallpaper for specific monitor on Windows with Python?
The code below takes an image and sets it as the desktop wallpaper for all my monitors, but how can I set the wallpaper for just one specific monitor?
import os
import ctypes


path = os.path.abspath("wallpaper3.jpg")
assert os.path.exists(path)
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)

I don't want to rely on third party tools like calling the DisplayFusion CLI - I'm trying to solve this in Python directly.
I also don't want to use the workaround of tiling multiple images together and setting the wallpaper mode to Tile, because this breaks as soon as the user changes resolution, monitor positions, or wants to switch the wallpaper on one of the monitors. I just want to programmatically set the wallpaper on a specific display like how it works from this menu:


There is a HRESULT IDesktopWallpaper::SetWallpaper([in] LPCWSTR monitorID,[in] LPCWSTR wallpaper); API.

Thank you! Couldn't figure out how to implement that myself but used it to find this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74203777/3620725
