# How to set a desktop background with python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, background, wallpaper

This code does that when you run it, there will be a app that will have 2 buttons. If you click one the "local files" one, the windows explorer will pop up. And now I want to know how to when you select a picture in the explorer, the programme will set it as your windows desktop background.

````py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=900)
canvas.pack()

def addImage():
    slika = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="\n", title="Izberi sliko", 
        filetypes=(("JPEG", "*.jpeg"), ("PNG","*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))

selectImage = tk.Button(root, text="Local image", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#f6c1ff", command=addImage)
selectImage.pack()

ourLibrary = selectImage = tk.Button(root, text="WPManager library", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#f6c1ff")
selectImage.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1977694) may be useful

Answer (score 0):

*edit: in your case, use slika.name to access the chosen file's full path*

**EITHER A:**

Copy the relevant image to `C:\Users\wolf3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles`.

You might also want to check and delete `C:\Users\wolf3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper` if it exists.

Finally, call `os.system("rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters")`, a few times (3 or so- I have found it to be more realiable than one update), and your wallpaper should have updated.

**OR B:**

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
```

from
[How can I change my desktop background with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977694/how-can-i-change-my-desktop-background-with-python)

**NOTE:**

From personal experience and from the comments in the question above, `.bmp` files will definitely work with these methods, unfortunately I cannot guarantee any others will work consistently.

Comment: I have tried this method out with jpgs and they TEND to work

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work. I don't know what to put in "image.jpg" because I need to somehow store the user's choice of the background and then set it.

Comment: @Jackzy use a variable, that is basic python, if you don't understand that then well, I don't know, you need to take some basic python tutorials

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I know btw, I'm new to python, but I took some basic lessons.

Comment: use slika.name to access the full path of your chosen file