# Setting a desktop background with python ctypes library

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, background, ctypes

I tried to make a PC app to change backgrounds on your desktop, but I ran into an issue and it doesn't work. I used python tkinter library. Help is much appreciated!

```py
def addImage():
    pic = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="\n", title="Izberi sliko", 
        filetypes=(("JPEG", "*.jpeg"), ("PNG","*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pic.name, 0)


selectImage = tk.Button(root, text="Local image", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#f6c1ff", command=addImage)
selectImage.pack()
```

Comment: Don't think it's related to your problem but instead of `filedialog.askopenfile`, you might want to use `filedialog.askopenfilename`. It returns a string of the filename instead of a file object.

Comment: What doesn't work? Most likely a *dup* of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977694/how-can-i-change-my-desktop-background-with-python.

Comment: Try using `SystemParametersInfoW(...)` instead.  It works in my Windows 10 running Python 3.9.6.

Comment: The last parameter to SystemParametersInfo is wrong.  See duplicate.