# Setting desktop picture in OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, plist, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programatically change the background in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x)

Hi,

I've whipped together a small (in this case python, but the language is not important) script which gets a jpg from a webpage and sets it as the current background image in OSX (testing and coding on 10.6.3).

My question is how to effectuate the setting of the background image.

My current approach involves regex replacing the paths in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist and then restarting (killing) Finder.app.

The last part does not work, as restarting finder, by killing it, doesn't reset/re-initializes the plist.

Do anyone have a better idea, or if there's any kind of signal (i.e. from terminal) I can use? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

- Chuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programatically change the background in Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205)

Comment: Thanks! I did not find it when I searched. Perhabs my searching-skills aren't what they used to be. Thanks again :)