# killall Dock - all active windows maximize and appear on Desktop

Tags: python, image, applescript, macos-sierra

I have written python script to change desktop wallpaper.

After I change my wallpaper using the below code:

```
app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(imageAddress))
```

I have added

```
os.system("killall Dock")
```

The wallpaper successfully changes, but all the active but minimized windows maximize. My question is How do I refresh my Dock without changing the state of minimized/maximized windows?

I have also tried the below methods :

```
tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Milky Way.jpg"

osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Milky Way.jpg"'
```

My python code is below:

```
#from appscript import app, mactypes
import subprocess
import os

def change_desktop_wallpaper(imageAddress):
    #app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(imageAddress))
    #os.system("Killall Dock")
    Script = ''' osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Users/princechawla/timepass/quotesWall/myquotewallpaper.jpg" ' '''
    os.system(Script)
    #os.system(''' osascript -e tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Users/princechawla/timepass/quotesWall/myquotewallpaper.jpg" ''')
    #subprocess.Popen(Script , shell=True)
    #os.system("killall Dock")
```

None of the work without using `killall Dock`

I have asked the same question here :

[killall Dock - all active windows maximize and appear on Desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287162/killall-dock-all-active-windows-maximize-and-appear-on-desktop)

This might look like  duplicate of :

[programmatically change the background of mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x)

but none of the answers in any of the questions work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on the latest version of OSX Sierra

```
tell application "System Events" to set picture of current desktop to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Milky Way.jpg"
```

Comment: Is it working in a python script? You ran this using `os.system(script)` or using `subprocess.Popen(Script, shell=True)` ? I replaced this in my python script, the wallpaper isn't changing.

Comment: I just ran it as a plain old AppleScript.. It will keep your minimized and maximized windows intact

Comment: that too isn't working for me. I am not sure why though.